# Is WolframAlpha wrong about $ \lim_{x\to\infty}(x!)^{1/x}-\frac{x}{e} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need some help evaluating this limit... Wolfram says it blows up to infinity but I don't think so. I just can't prove it yet.

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}(x!)^{1/x}-\frac{x}{e} $$

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's formula?

Comment: If the limit is actually $\infty$, the sequence diverges very slow. With PARI/GP, I got about value $3$ for $x=2000000$

Comment: $\log(n!)\approx n\log n -n$

Comment: If Maple and I did not make any mistake you have
$$\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}-x/e = \frac{1}{2e}\ln(2\pi x) + O(1/x), \quad x\rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: @saulspatz unless I'm mistaken, your formula would imply that the limit does not blow up to infinity.

Comment: @BlakeSteines Now that I look again, I think it's inconclusive.  It says that the $\log (n!^{1/n}) grows like $\log n$ but that doesn't really decide matters.

Comment: @gammatester Can you post the details as an answer?  I'm not convinced by any of the posted answers.

Comment: @saulspatz: There are not much details, but I post it.

Answer (score 5):

It diverges, albeit slowly.

By [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), the function approaches

$$f(x)=(2\pi x)^{1/x}\left( \frac xe\right)-\frac xe=\left(\frac xe\right)\left( (2\pi x)^{1/x}-1\right).$$

Now it is true that $(2\pi x)^{1/x}$ goes to $1$ as $x\to\infty$, but we need more information. Using L'Hospital's rule,

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2\pi x)^{1/x}-1}{e/x}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-(2 \pi x)^{1/x} x^{-2} (\log (2 \pi  x)-1)}{-ex^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-1}(2 \pi x)^{1/x} (\log (2 \pi  x)-1)\\
&=\infty
\end{align}
since the factor $e^{-1}(2 \pi x)^{1/x}$ is bounded and nonzero and $\log(2\pi x)-1\to\infty$.

---

As an aside, check out the harmonic prime series $1/2+1/3+1/5+1/7+\cdots$. This diverges, but so slowly that the first million primes don't even make it past $3$.

Comment: What then, is incorrect about my logic here (using n! ~ nlogn - n): (x!)^(1/x) = x/e, then (1/x)*(xlogx -x) = ln(x) - 1, then ln(x) -1 = ln(x) -1, so the limits should be equal?

Comment: That the logarithms approach the same number tells you that their quotient approaches $1,$ not that their difference approaches $0$.

Comment: ** using log(n!) = nlogn - n

Comment: First, I think you're missing an extra $\log$ on the left. So if you have $(x!)^{1/x}=x/e$, then taking $\log$ of both sides would give $\frac 1x \log(x\log x-x)=\log x-1$, or $\log(x\log x-x)=x\log x-1$. But also it makes no sense to begin with the assumption $(x!)^{1/x}=x/e$. The solution here would only show you where the function has a root.

Comment: I upvoted this, but now I have doubts.  Stirling's approximation is asymptotic, so is it valid to use in in computing a difference?

Comment: @ElliotG I think you have one too many logs on the LHS

Answer (score 2):

I used a simple one-liner and asked  Maple 7 to `simplify(series(GAMMA(x+1)^(1/x)-x/exp(1), x=infinity,3));` and the answer is `1/2*(ln(2)+ln(Pi)+ln(x)+2*O(1/x)*exp(1))*exp(-1)`,  this can be converted to  mathematical notation as:
$$\Gamma\left(x+1\right)^{1/x}-\frac{x}{e} = \frac{1}{2e}\ln(2\pi x) + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \quad x\rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: Thanks.  I wish we could see the underlying reasoning.

Comment: I suppose that any expansion of $\log(p!)$ followed by Taylor series would confirm it. By the way, $+1$. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as in previous answers, considering $$A=(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{x}{e}=B-\frac{x}{e}$$
$$B=(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}\implies \log(B)={\frac{1}{x}}\log(x!)$$ Now, using Stirling approximation
$$\log(B)={\frac{1}{x}}\left(x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({x}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)$$
$$\log(B)= (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2x} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({x}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$B=e^{\log(B)}=\frac{x}{e}+\frac{\log (2 \pi )+\log \left({x}\right)}{2 e}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$A=\frac{\log (2 \pi x)}{2 e}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\tag 1$$ Pushing further the expansion of $B$, you would get
$$A=\frac{\log (2 \pi x)}{2 e}+\frac{3 \log ^2\left({2 \pi  x}\right)+2}{24 e x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\tag 2$$ For illustration purposes, let $x=10^k$ and computing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & (1) & (2) & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.761595453 & 0.843495044 & 0.849934276 \\
 2 & 1.185132311 & 1.204528536 & 1.204745228 \\
 3 & 1.608669170 & 1.612217034 & 1.612222301 \\
 4 & 2.032206029 & 2.032770401 & 2.032770506
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: (+1) So you have confirmed that the Maple expression is correct.